# Запретить нажатие div`ов с некоторым классом чаще чем раз в секунду

Tags: javascript, html, веб-программирование

Проблема состоит в следующем: если часто нажимать на один из div`ов с классом "list", которые вызывают функцию "fnc", запрос отправляется слишком часто, и сервер возвращает некорректный результат. Как запретить выполнение функции "fnc" чаще чем раз в секунду?

Answer (score 0):

Просто делаете задержку в одну секунду(добавлять строку после функции):

```
setTimeout(fnc, 1000);
```